# Can I use prepositional phrases as complements?

Tags: complements

As in "I feel at ease" or "he seems at ease",

Can I say "I became in a bad mood" or "he makes me in a bad mood"?

Comment: No, the sentence seems awkward.

Comment: No: "become" doesn't generally take PPs. And "make" doesn't license an objective PC like "in a bad mood".

Comment: "He put me in a bad mood" and "He left me in a bad mood" are valid - see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+me+in+a+bad+mood&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)